# Usage of the word Requisite

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english

I have a form with mandatory input field for Phone Number or Account Number. Would it be correct to name this fields as 'Requisite' ? Is it correct to name PhoneNumber/AccountNumber as Requisite ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming is off topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Do you mean 'required'? Don't use requisite for a form, it is much rarer and won't be understood.

Comment: @Mitch exactly , i mean required

Comment: @Z.R.T. Yes, 'mandatory' and 'required' are synonyms. 'Required' is the preferred label in user interfaces. 'Requisite' is very inappropriate here.

Comment: @Mitch what is the common word English speaking people use instead of 'requisite' while filling up the form ?

Comment: @Z.R.T. The word I gave already multiple times, 'required'.